# How do I get the inner html of a wysihtml5

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have two wysihtml5 fields that appear on a page. I would like to be able to update the textarea `class="vLargeTextField"` with text from the `class="vLargeTextField wysihtml5-editor"` in real time, and vice versa. If I update the `id="user_input"` `class="vLargeTextField wysihtml5-editor"` the `id="user_input"` `class="vLargeTextField"` should update for the appropriate input.

I tried doing a few things along the lines of:

```
Userinput1 = $(".wysihtml5-sandbox").contents().find("body").html()
```

It works great if I only had one editor on the screen. It returns `user_input`, but if I update `user_input2`, the with a similar line the code will not. Also if I update `user_input` or `user_input2`, I would like to update the appropriate `class="vLargeTextField wysihtml5-editor"` with the input from user_input 1 or 2.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciate. See the code below:

```
<div name="newboxes" id="user_input" class="text">
    <div style="display:inline-block">
<textarea class="vLargeTextField" cols="80" id="user_input" name="results" rows="20" style="width: 640px; height: 200px; margin: 0px auto; display: none;"></textarea>    
    <iframe class="wysihtml5-sandbox" security="restricted" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" width="0" height="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-collapse: separate; border: 0.9090908765792847px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); clear: none; display: inline-block; float: none; margin: 0px auto; outline: rgb(85, 85, 85) none 0px; outline-offset: 0px; padding: 3.9914772510528564px 5.994318008422852px; position: static; top: auto; left: auto; right: auto; bottom: auto; z-index: auto; vertical-align: middle; text-align: start; box-sizing: content-box; -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0745098) 0px 0.9090908765792847px 0.9090908765792847px 0px inset; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0745098) 0px 0.9090908765792847px 0.9090908765792847px 0px inset; border-top-right-radius: 3.9914772510528564px; border-bottom-right-radius: 3.9914772510528564px; border-bottom-left-radius: 3.9914772510528564px; border-top-left-radius: 3.9914772510528564px; width: 640px; height: 200px;"></iframe>

    #document
        <html>
        <body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" contenteditable="true" class="vLargeTextField wysihtml5-editor" spellcheck="true" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(85, 85, 85); cursor: auto; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13.63636302947998px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; line-height: 20px; letter-spacing: normal; text-align: start; text-decoration: none; text-indent: 0px; text-rendering: auto; word-break: normal; word-wrap: break-word; word-spacing: 0px;">
        "Some Text Here"
        </body>
        </html>
    </div>
</div>

<div name="newboxes" id="user_input2" class="text">
    <div style="display:inline-block">
    <textarea class="vLargeTextField" cols="80" id="user_input2" name="results" rows="20" style="width: 640px; height: 200px; margin: 0px auto; display: none;"></textarea>
    <iframe class="wysihtml5-sandbox" security="restricted" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" width="0" height="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-collapse: separate; border: 0.9090908765792847px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); clear: none; display: inline-block; float: none; margin: 0px auto; outline: rgb(85, 85, 85) none 0px; outline-offset: 0px; padding: 3.9914772510528564px 5.994318008422852px; position: static; top: auto; left: auto; right: auto; bottom: auto; z-index: auto; vertical-align: middle; text-align: start; box-sizing: content-box; -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0745098) 0px 0.9090908765792847px 0.9090908765792847px 0px inset; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0745098) 0px 0.9090908765792847px 0.9090908765792847px 0px inset; border-top-right-radius: 3.9914772510528564px; border-bottom-right-radius: 3.9914772510528564px; border-bottom-left-radius: 3.9914772510528564px; border-top-left-radius: 3.9914772510528564px; width: 640px; height: 200px;"></iframe>

    #document
        <html>
        <body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" contenteditable="true" class="vLargeTextField wysihtml5-editor" spellcheck="true" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(85, 85, 85); cursor: auto; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13.63636302947998px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; line-height: 20px; letter-spacing: normal; text-align: start; text-decoration: none; text-indent: 0px; text-rendering: auto; word-break: normal; word-wrap: break-word; word-spacing: 0px;">
        "Some Text Here"
        </body>
        </html>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you have two iFrames that have the same className and you are tying to get the html out of both of them?

Comment: Like @ryanc1256 pointed out ..if you have 2 iframes with the same .className, use each() in jQuery, otherwise target the iframes via the id's seperately

Comment: or another way is, if you don't have any other iFrames just use iframe:nth-child(1) in jQuery... both ways that @Robert said will work fine as well and probably less confusing...

Comment: @ryanc1256 Yes, that is exactly what I am tryiny to do. But I would only like to get the html to update the related textarea on .keyup

Comment: then just add an .keyup event on the textarea and the find the corresponding element in the .keyup event... and change the html of the iFrame with the techniques me and Robort said...

Comment: I guess where I am stuck is i was wondering how to access id.class. class in other words $('#user_input2.wysihtml5-sandbox.vLargeTextField .wysihtml5-editor') or something along those lines.

Comment: @ryanc1256 I guess thats the problem I am having issues with. I cannot figure out how to access that element. .vLargeTextField .wysihtml5-editor that corresponds with the related input, I can take it from there.

Comment: @user1462141 So here is my solution... http://jsfiddle.net/qJBBn/ just put ids on both...

Comment: Anyway, I wonder why you use 3.9914772510528564px as padding. Can you explan it?

Answer (score 0):

Your question answered my problem.
In your case I just added an ID into jQuery selector

```
Userinput = $("#user_input .wysihtml5-sandbox").contents().find("body").html()
Userinput1 = $("#user_input1 .wysihtml5-sandbox").contents().find("body").html()
```